# Restore Pictures folder in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: home-directory

I've accidentally deleted the Pictures folder in `/home/my_username`. I've tried to re-create that folder but it seems that the system doesn't understand it. All the pictures I take from the screenshot program, shutter, save from the web... automatically go to `/home/my_username`, not `/home/my_username/Pictures`

How do I restore the default Pictures folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the folder under your home as `/home/username/Pictures`.

Then open `Shutter` and go to `Edit` menu > `Preferences`.

There change the save directory with **automatic save** to the folder you just created and save the changes made. Now it will work and save automatically to any folder you want.

[image]

If it does not work, please comment.

Comment: Thank you, it works :) But what wrong with default Pictures folder?

Comment: @Finn : I do not know what's wrong of we delete and make same `Pictures` folder again ! I use the above way to organize screenshots in a separate folder so, I know this. :-)